# VB6 excel application hangs when run concurrently with C# excel application

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vb6

I have a Vb6 application which processes some files and write to an Excel file which runs perfectly. I have another C#.net application which also processes some files and run perfectly. I have scheduled these jobs in tidal to run at the same time. I observed that the C#.net application works fine. But the Vb6 application works till the Excel writing method. The files are getting processed but the writing to the excel part is in pending status always.

If we observe the task manager i can see some excel.exe processes are still there without closing. I have done necessary steps for Garbage collection.

Below are the codes for vb6 and C#.net respectively for object disoposal

```
 excellApplication1.Workbooks.Close

    excellApplication1.Quit


    If Not objWorkSheet Is Nothing Then Set objWorkSheet = Nothing
    If Not excellApplication1Is Nothing Then Set excellApplication1 = Nothing


    ErrHandler:    

        excellApplication1.Workbooks.Close

        excellApplication1.Quit


        If Not objWorkSheet Is Nothing Then Set objWorkSheet = Nothing
        If Not excellApplication1 Is Nothing Then Set excellApplication1=Nothing
```

C# Code for releasing object.

```
   Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Application1);
   Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Application2);
   Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Application3);
```

What i observe is when the C#.NET application runs EXCEL.exe process is shown in task manager. VB6  (not VB.NET)application cannot write in to Excel file.For the vb6 application only this part is pending, hence the application hangs without completion.

Can anyone throw some light on this?
Edit: both applications are trying to write to different files.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do:

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs("" + saveasPath + ".xlsx");

xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);

xlApp.Quit();
releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
releaseObject(xlApp);
releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
GC.Collect();
xlWorkSheet = null;
xlWorkBook = null;
xlApp = null;

Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
Process.Start("" + saveasPath + ".xlsx");


private void releaseObject(object obj)
{
  try
  {
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
    obj = null;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    obj = null;
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
  finally
  {
   GC.Collect();
  }
}
```

Comment: vb6 not vb.net application

Comment: your answer is in vb6.net. I think its not with the garbage collection. The 2 jobs are working fine when run at different time. The issue happens when both are running at the same time

Comment: Both applications writing to same excel file simultaneously?

Comment: Which one hangs c# or vb6?

Comment: vb6 application